# consulta ui.router asigna un # antes de las rutas

Tags: angularjs, nodejs, angularjs-injector

estoy probando ui.router pero tengo un problema siempre que el ui-sref le antecede un #

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>

    <title>Indice</title>
    <script src="/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="/satellizer/satellizer.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/index2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<a ui-sref="register">Register</a>
<a ui-sref="auth">Auth</a>

<a ui-sref="me">Me</a>

</body>
</html>
```

index2.js

```
angular.module("app",["satellizer","ui.router"])
.config(function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider){
$stateProvider.state('register',{
    url:'/api/register',
});
$stateProvider.state('auth',{
    url:'/api/auth',
});
$stateProvider.state('me',{
    url:'/me',
});

});
```

ejemplo:
en vez de irse a localhost:3000/api/router.
se va a localhost:3000/#/api/router y no redirige .

Comment: ui-router usa el modelo de [single-page application (SPA)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application), que usa las secciones de la página (lo que hay después del "#") para indicar la navegación. La ruta es correcta, el problema de que no te cargue la página es por otro motivo. Enséñanos a qué página quieres ir y cómo indicas la navegación a la misma.

Answer (score -1):

Debes especificar en el header que agregue '/' en vez de '#'. Agrega esta línea: <base href="/" />

Por ejemplo:

```
<head>
    <base href="/" />

</head>
```

Además debes habilitar el mode html5.

```
app.config(["$locationProvider", function($locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```